# Sitecore Rocks stuck in the "Add New Item" menu whilst connecting using Good Old Web Sevice?

Tags: sitecore-rocks, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013, and Sitecore 8.1. My project is configured using the Good Old Web Service.

Whenever I try to add a new item, all I get in the dialog where I'm supposed to choose the template for the new item is a screen which reads "Loading...", like so:

[image: like so]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling several versions, I am always getting the same behavior - effectively preventing me from adding Items through Sitecore Rocks.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Any errors logged in your Sitecore log files?

Comment: Nothing, nada, zilch. This is a problem as a lot of the tutorials I'm reading about customisation of Sitecore Analytics use Rocks - I can't do much without the ability to add new Items.
Surely there should be a log about this somewhere..?

Comment: what user did you use when you created connection to the site? Are you sure that it has a permission to read templates?

Comment: It's a Sitecore administrator - the same one I am using in my day-to-day development.

Comment: I'll tr installing Visual Studio Express 2015 and see if I get the same error there.

Comment: Didn't work - tried with Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: Changing the web service type from Good Old to Hard Rock (and ticking both checkboxes that'll automatically update the components) fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me:

- I uninstalled Sitecore Rocks;
- I closed Visual Studio;
- I searched my ENTIRE hard drive for "Sitecore Rocks" and deleted **every single file and folder** with this name. NOTE: a lot of those files live under C:\Users\[username]\AppData folder, so you will need the appropriate privileges to access them.

I reinstalled Sitecore Rocks and everything was fine.